# Matlab: y-label isn't shown in small figure window

Tags: matlab, size, label, figure

I'm using the following code:

```
x = linspace(0, 9, 10);
y1 = x;
y2 = x.^2;
y3 = x.^4;

myfig = figure('Position', [500 500 400 320]); %[left, bottom, width, height]:
ax1 = gca;
hold on
p1 = plot(x,y1,'x--r');
p2 = plot(x,y2,'*-b');

xlabel('blaaa');
ylabel('fooo'); 
xlim([0 max(x)]);
ax2 = axes('Position',get(ax1,'Position'),...
       'XAxisLocation','top',...
       'YAxisLocation','right',...
       'Color','none',...
       'XTickLabel', [],...
       'XColor','k','YColor','k');
ylabel(ax2, 'asdasd');
linkaxes([ax1 ax2],'x');
hold on
p3 = plot(x,y3,'s:g','Parent',ax2);

legend([p1 p2 p3], {'one', 'two', 'three'}, 'Location', 'NorthWest');
```

whereas the right y-label isnt shown: Is there a way to show it by decreasing either the margin between the left-edge and the left y-label or by decreasing the width of the actual plotted data without resizing the figure window?

Thanks

**Edit**: Added an image:

[image]
Either decrease the red margin or the 'green' size, because wherre the blue arrow is, the y-label is now shown anymore since it doesn't fit!

Comment: i don't want to run the code. can you add a figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the line:

```
ax1 = gca;
```

with:

```
ax1 = axes('Position',[0.11 0.11 0.75 0.812]);
```

To [manually](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f1-33513.html) set the [axis position/size](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#zmw57dd0e31324) in [normalized units](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#zmw57dd0e31739).

[image]

Comment: Thanks it seems to work, didn't know you could easily set the first axes!